# Creating reusable - runtime calculated StyleSheet styles

Tags: javascript, css, react-native

As far as I can tell, the docs for React Native showcase hard coded values for the styles.

I'm an experienced OOP and I want to build more reusable components. For instance, React Native docs teaches you this approach to design your elements:

```
renderButton: function() {
  return (
    <TouchableHighlight onPress={this._onPressButton}>
      <Image
        style={styles.button}
        source={require('image!myButton')}
      />
    </TouchableHighlight>
  );
},

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  button: {
    width: 80,
  },
});
```

As far as I can tell, there's no good solution for having a varying button component if done this way.

Ideally, I want to be able to do this:

```
class Button extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      //render stuff according to passed in attributes
    );
  }
}

//usage
<Button width="50" height="40" onPress={this.buttonPressed}/>
<Button width="100" height="20" onPress={this.anotherButtonPressed}/>
```

However, being the beginner in JavaScript that I am, I'm having trouble defining a class capable of doing this. Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Did you mean to imply that there was a React Native class named "Component"? Or that you want to create both a Component, and a Button class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Expand existing style definitions using spread operator

You can expand the predefined styles with some additional definitions by using the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator). Just expand an empty object (`...{}`) with the predefined styles (`styles.button`) and the additional ones (`{width, height}`).

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  button: {
    backgroundColor: 'blue'
  }
});

export default class Button extends Component {
  render() {
    const {width, height} = this.props;
    // Combine the predefined styles with some additional definitions
    const style = [...{}, styles.button, { width, height}]

    return (
      <View style={style}>
        <Text>Button</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Looks a bit foreign (due to my unfamiliarity for js), but the idea that you're grabbing heigh/width from props is exactly what I'm looking for. 

I'm unclear as to how `const {width, height} = this.props` work, and same with how `const style` work.

Comment: `const{width, height} = this.props` is just a shorthand for `const width = this.props.width',... using a [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

Comment: Yes, testing this out now. Thanks for the clarification

Comment: So does this answer eventually solves your question?

Comment: Hey, yes! The spread operator was a bit confusing but I managed to get something going with my code. This works fine for my needs.

Answer (score 1):

Try doing this:

button.js

```
export default class Button extends Component {
  render(){
    return (
      <View style={{ width:this.props.width, height: this.props.height }}>
        <Text>{this.props.text}</Text>
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

Then, use it in your view like this:

```
import Button from './button'

<Button height={50} width={200} text="Hey, this is a button" />
```

Comment: Thanks again Nader, mind if you explain the differences between `export default` compared to not having it? Also, coming from an OOP background, I'm a bit confused as to how `styles` has access to `this.props.width`. 

I am under the impression that `props` is like a dictionary for instance variables of a class.

Comment: My apologies, I made a mistake and edited my answer after testing it. This.props is not available outside of the component declaration.

Comment: Export default is the es6/es2015 Class definition way of declaring react components. You can just as easily say React.createClass({)} (es5) and get the same thing!  Anything passed down to the component will be available as this.props in the component, the way height, width, and text are available (even functions, which are commonly passed down as props as well).